# Hide viewPager tabs dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I would like to hide tabs in specific fragment. I have a MainActivity and two tabs - fragments (I am using viewPager). However, in third fragment I need to hide these tabs and show only the toolbar.

I know how to hide toolbar, but nowhere I find how to hide tabs dynamically.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); //your tablayout id
```

*For Hide*

```
 tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE
```

*For Show*

```
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it fragment I have no access to ID's in activity, haven't I?

Comment: I assuming that tab is part of xml use in your activity so you can intialize and create function in activity to hide tab and in fragment you can call that function using ((YourActivity)getActivity).methodtohidetab.